# Moto Guzzi V85tt -- Immobilizer antenna short circuit error B0005 after light install

Tags: troubleshooting, wiring, short

I recently added some auxiliary lights to my V85tt motorcycle. I used Cyclops lights with a Skene controller to tie them into the high beams. They are sold as a pair.

I believe everything was installed correctly; the bike runs normally and the lights work correctly, including switching to high power when I use the high beam switch and running at 20% power when I don't. This bike has an RFid immobilizer built into the ignition switch; After the installation, I am getting two dashboard error codes: B0004 (key read error) and B0005 (short circuit to positive in immobilizer antenna). Now I have to enter my 5-digit code every time I start the bike, which is not ideal, but at least I can still ride.

The error has to be my fault; there's no way the timing is a coincidence. But as far as I know, I never touched the antenna circuit. I would appreciate any suggestions. Here are all the details.

A diagram of the install:
[image: diagram of install]
I used posi-taps to connect to existing wires; for switched power I used the USB accessory circuits that my bike has, one under the seat and one behind the dash. I also used a posi-tap to get the high beam signal from the headlight side of the headlight wiring harness.

The Skene installation instructions are below, with one small change: *there is only one thick red wire to battery on the copy of the instructions included in my package*:

[image: Skene IQ-275 LED installation]

Are there any potential sources of a false short that I should be considering? Is there any way I could have actually created a short to positive without ever touching the antenna's circuit?

I can provide the motorcycle's wiring diagram if that would be helpful but I'm guessing it's overkill. Thanks for any and all suggestions!

UPDATE

There are two wires that travel from the dash to the immobilizer antenna. On the wiring diagram, they are labeled 'antenna a' and 'antenna b'. This morning I used my multimeter to check connectivity between these two wires by disconnecting the connector and putting the probes into the connector holes. I measured no connectivity. It seems to me that a simple antenna should just look like a length of wire when it's not in use -- does this indicate that the antenna really is just broken? Why would this cause a 'short to power' error?

Answer (score 1):

The antenna was faulty and was replaced under warranty. The service guys had no idea. I guess I'll never know!